# Can ',,' be aliased to '..'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sometimes when I want to change to the parent directory, I mistakenly type `cd ,,` instead of `cd ..`. Is there a way I can make bash consider these statements to be the same? I never use commas in my commands. Ideally, I would like to alias `,,` to `..`. When I tried this, it didn't work. Why didn't this work? How else can I approach this problem?

```
$ alias ,,=..
$ cd ,,
-bash: cd: ,,: No such file or directory
```

Comment: An alias is a program to run, not an argument to the program; so `$ ,,` would complain, as such: `bash: ..: Is a directory`. (In other words, it's not an executable.)

Comment: @jpaugh: A clearer way to say that is: alias expansion only happens on the first "word" of a command.  So as you say, it only works for command names, not args.  (And you couldn't even `alias 'cd ,,'='cd ..'`.  Well, you could, but you'd have to run it as `cd\ ,,` to make it all one word.)

Comment: Consider zsh. It has global aliases, so `alias -g ,,=..` and `cd ,,` works as you expect it to.

Comment: I have this: `function c() { cd "${1-..}"; }` It's just like `cd` but the default behavior (when no argument given) is to to the parent directory (instead of the home directory as for `cd`).

Comment: Lateral thinking: `find / -type d -exec ln -s .. {}/,, \;`... ;-)

Comment: Note that it is possible that there is an actual directory called `,,` (try `mkdir ,,`).

Comment: Imho: don't do this. Using aliases to cover up typographic errors is a bad practice. Those errors can end up in copy-pasted code or screencasts. It won't work in other hosts or accounts. And such modification (depending on how it's implemented) could cause other, unexpected, difficult to debug errors. My suggestion: if you mistype a command, simply type it again ;-).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### ZSH:

If you'r using `zsh` `alias -g ,,=".."` is what you need, but this will cause ",," to be expanded everywhere, not only when used with `cd`.

From `man zshbuiltins`:

> If  the  `-g`  flag  is  present, define a global alias; global aliases are expanded even if they do not occur in command position.

#### BASH:

If restricted to `bash` (as the question is tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)), read the following:

This is a pure-alias solution, as requested, **however** this will do more than required possibly frustrating the user (see the warning at the end of my post).

Quoting `man bash`:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Therefore it's enough to alias `cd` with an extra space (to allow expanding of its next argument) and then alias `,,` to `..`. See that

```
alias cd='cd '
alias ,,='..'
```

gives exactly what you need.

Note that this is correct not only for `bash` (and its `alias` implementation), but all POSIX-compilant shells. Quoting an example from `man 1p alias` (the manual does not describe this feature explicitly, only through an example):

> 4. Set up nohup so that it can deal with an argument that is itself an alias name:
>
>    ```
>           alias nohup="nohup "
>    ```

**Warning:**
As @PeterCordes writes in his comment, it will automatically cause *other* aliases to expand when written after `cd`. It may require you to write `cd \grep` if you want to change directory to one named `grep` but your `grep` is an alias for `grep --color=auto`. Without the backslash, `cd` will report "too many arguments" error (you can't `cd` to two directories at once)!.

Comment: That's a clever but nasty hack.  I wouldn't want to do that; too easy for that to accidentally bite you.  e.g. if you have an alias for a command you commonly run, and you want to `cd` into a directory of its source code.  Or other collisions between your aliases and common directory names.  Like `cd dr` would expand to `cd disown -r` for me, with this alias.  Anyway, much better to override builtin `cd` with a function for stuff like this, IMO.

Comment: +1 for pure-alias solution (I learnt something). At the same time I agree with Peter's comment. Some kind of explicit warning should be added to your answer, I think.

Answer (score 59):

Aliases aren't meant to do this, but you can create a function called `cd` that is a wrapper for the real `cd`. This one works for me! Just put it into your `.bash_profile` or your profile file of choice.

```
cd () { if [ "$1" = ",," ]; then builtin cd ..; else builtin cd "$@"; fi; }
```

Or, with comments and pretty formatting:

```
cd ()
{
  if [ "$1" = ",," ]; then  # if first argument is ",,"...
    builtin cd ..           # call the builtin cd with ".." instead...
  else
    builtin cd "$@"         # else call builtin cd with original arguments 
  fi
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks @derobert for pointing out that `if then else` is better here than `&& ||`. Also, I just realized (**facepalm**) that this implementation will only work if any non-path arguments (i.e. `-L -P`) are not the first argument. So be warned, if you have a bad habit of typing `cd -L ,,` this isn't going to help you. And that is non-trivial to handle correctly, I think.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe I think the "comments and pretty formatting" version would be better with an if-then-else.

Comment: Wow folks, lots of good ideas. I see you are using the edit feature to take care of the fixes needed. I didn't spend much time testing it. :)

Comment: Alternatively, just overwrite `$1` before executing the built-in: `cd () { [ "$1" = ",," ] && set .. ; cd "$@"; }`

Comment: @TobySpeight `set .. "${@:2}"`, or you lose anything after the first argument.

Comment: Also, technically `..` doesn't have to be the first argument; `cd` in `bash` can take a variety of options (`-P`, `-L`, `-@`, `-e`).

Comment: You need to use if here. Otherwise, you have a bug: if `builtin cd ..` fails, the `||` part will execute. That is a very uncommon occurrence, but it can happen (e.g., on an NFS mount).

Comment: @derobert I see your point and (kind of) agree, but this thing is for the occasional typo. So point 1) the chances of a typo and a rare NFS mount bug happening simultaneously are *really* slim, and 2) if you make a typo, an error is hardly surprising...and this would be the "original" error anyways of saying that no directory ",," exists.

Comment: @derobert But the more I think of it, the less reason I see to leave it as-is. ;)

Comment: @BenjiWiebe change it if for no other reason than someone might see it and think it's a valid if-then-else and use it somewhere where it matters. Examples should show good practices, not tricks that sort of work in a few limited use cases.

Answer (score 29):

Aliases must be the *first word* of a command.  Also, the alias must be substituted for *a word* therefore no spaces).

> [Bash Reference Manual: Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases)
>
> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for **a word** when it is used as
>   the **first word** of a simple command.

You could alias both `..` and `,,` to be `cd ..`.

```
$ alias ..="cd .."
$ alias ,,="cd .."
$ cd /tmp && pwd
/tmp
$ ,, && pwd
/
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I do! :D these two dots/commas are much easier to type than `cd ..`

Comment: +1, that's not a bad idea at all. Another way to do it for `..`  in Bash is with `shopt -s autocd` which lets you change to any directory by just entering its name. Of course you still the alias for `,,`

Comment: [Me too](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/f9619b2e764b00dfb5ddcf5405371b13ba49ebaf/code/shellscript/init/joeysaliases#L291-L295) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to make `..` change the directory is to enable Bash's [`autocd`
feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
shopt -s autocd
```

That'll automatically change the directory when you enter the name of one:

```
~$ /tmp
cd /tmp
/tmp$
```

You still have to make an alias for `,,` but that can be done with just `alias ,,=..`

Answer (score 2):

There's already <strike>an app</strike> a script for that: https://github.com/shyiko/commacd (no affiliation with Stanley Shuyiko).

> `commacd` exports three commands: `,` (for jumping forward), `,,` (backward) and `,,,` (backward+forward):
>
> All three of them try to match by prefix first. Only if no results are found, will they fallback to substring (fuzzy) matching

To answer your question the script aliases commas to three functions it defines:

```
alias ,=_commacd_forward
alias ,,=_commacd_backward
alias ,,,=_commacd_backward_forward
```